# What is common pratice with return statements in functions?

Tags: python, list, return

I'm having trouble with understanding when to use the `return` function. In the below function my intuition is that the `return` statement should be there to return the modified list, but my TA said is was redundant which I didn't quite understand why. Any clarification on when to correctly use `return` statement and on common practise would be highly appreciated.

```
p = [2,0,1]
q = [-2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]
p1 = [0,0,0,0]

#Without return statement
def drop_zeros1(p_list):
    """drops zeros at end of list"""
    i = 0 
    while i < len(p_list):
            if p_list[-1]==0:
                p_list.pop(-1)
            else:
                break

#With return statement
def drop_zeros(p_list):
    """drops zeros at end of list"""
    i = 0 
    while i < len(p_list):
            if p_list[-1]==0:
                p_list.pop(-1)
            else:
                return p_list
                break
```

Also why the output is inconsistent when used on the list p1, it only removes the last 0 when it should remove all zeroes?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Both functions stop iterating as soon as a non-zero is encountered.

Comment: second break is pointless if you return on previous line

Comment: that is the point, so when p1 is passed into the function it should return an empty list

Comment: also the list gets modified inside the funcion scope, so unless you want the function to actually output something, a `return` is redundant

Comment: @Mstaino But is it common practise to modify a list directly or is it so that you usually modify a copy of the list to preserve the original?

Comment: The convention is to mutate an argument and return `None` *or* return a new value, leaving the argument untouched, not both.

Comment: In my opinion and understanding it is a bad practice to modify a list in a loop, and it is a bad practice to modify a global variable inside a function

Comment: Why do you use `i`? It does not seem to serve a purpose.

Comment: @trincot if I don't use `i` I get an IndexError when the list has no elements as the function searches for the -1 element

Comment: Yes, but you can just replace `i` with 0, and it will still work... You never modify `i`, so there is no need to use that variable.

Comment: Why check one condition in the `while` condition, and another in an `if ... break`? Seems more logical to do `while p_list and p_list[-1]==0: p_list.pop()`

Comment: @Mstaino Would you be able to provide a "good practise" solution for this problem? Won't be using it, just want to get a picture of good practise.

Comment: It's ... less than ideal to use a global variable at all inside a function, because now your function's behavior is subject to change depending on what someone else might do to the value of the variable. Global *constants* are fine, but strive to use function parameters where possible.

Comment: @trincot Why I did it is because of lack of experience, examples of "good practises" is what I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for the insight, no global variables inside functions!

Comment: Good practice to me would be to subclass list and define your `drop_zeros1` and `drop_zeros` as member mutating themselves rather than a global list.

Comment: Generally, I avoid functions that modify their inputs at all costs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention is that functions either mutate the argument(s) given to it, or return the result, but then leave the arguments untouched.

This is to prevent that a user of your function would do this:

```
template = [1, 2, 0, 0]
shorter = drop_zeros(template)
print ("input was ", template, " and output was ", shorter)
```

They would expect this output:

> input was [1, 2, 0, 0] and output was [1, 2]

... but be surprised to see:

> input was [1, 2] and output was [1, 2]

So to avoid this, you would *either*:

- not return the modified argument, but `None`. That way the above code would output `...and output was None`, and the user would understand that the function is not designed to return the result.
- return the result, but ensure that the argument retains its original content

So in your case you could do:

```
def drop_zeros(p_list):
    """drops zeroes at end of list, in-place"""
    while p_list and p_list[-1] == 0:
        p_list.pop()
```

Note that the `else` can be better integrated into the `while` condition. No more need to do an explicit `break`. Also `.pop()` does not need -1 as argument: it is the default.

If you prefer a function that returns the result, then the logic should be somewhat different:

```
def drop_zeros(p_list):
    """returns a copy of the list without the ending zeroes"""
    for i in range(len(p_list)-1, -1, -1):
         if p_list[i] != 0:
             return p_list[0:i+1]
    return []
```

Now the code is designed to do:

```
template = [1, 2, 0, 0]
shorter = drop_zeros(template)
print ("input was ", template, " and output was ", shorter)
# input was [1, 2, 0, 0] and output was [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation, highly appreciate the time and effort, it's really clear to me now with the user example you put at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Your TA is right, the return is redundant because of what in python is called *aliasing*.

Basically, in your function, `p_list` is a reference (NOT a copy) to whatever list you pass in when you call the function. Since you use `pop`, which mutates the list in-place when extracting an element, `p_list` will be modified and this modification will be visible outside the function:

```
drop_zeros(q) # from here, in the function, p_list is q (as in, exactly the same object)
print(q)
```

prints

```
[-2,1,0,0,1]
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying why it is redundant. On a side note the print should be [2,0,1], since the function is suppose to remove all zeroes at the end of a list until it encounters a non zero.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the docstring (or the code beyond the `pop`). I'll change example ;)